# Decrease FPS of a camera using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, frame-rate

I'm reading frames from a camera which displays which has original fps set to 25. I'm trying to reduce the FPS of this to about 6-7.

I'm reading multiple cameras at the same time and appending the frames to the respective camera's `deque`. I've used threading here.

So, far I'm doing this but no luck

```
while True:
    try:
        # Read next frame from stream and insert into deque
        status, frame = self.capture.read()
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (640, 360))

        if status:
            self.deque.append(frame)
        else:
            self.capture.release()
            self.online = False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
frame_count = 1
        
while True:
    try:
    # Read next frame from stream and insert into deque
    status, frame = self.capture.read()
                    
    if frame_count % 4 == 0:
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (640, 360))

        if status:
            self.deque.append(frame)
        else:
            self.capture.release()
            self.online = False
    frame_count += 1
```